# multiple clients communication using sockets in java

Tags: java

Let Suppose i have 100 clients in my office.I have to make an application in which one main thread is running which is waiting for any client's connection and once connection is established IP-address of that client is send to the server(I m done with that).Also server can send message to any of the clients individually or can send a broadcast message to all clients.(This part of application is not understandable by me).kindly help me.
sorry for my bad English in advance.

Comment: look at [UDP broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address)

Comment: also look at [Multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast)

Comment: What question do you have?

Comment: i simply want to communicate with any number of clients individually @ControlAltDel

Comment: Here you go https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/multicastsocket-net/java-net-multicastsocket-example/

Answer (score 0):

> i simply want to communicate with any number of clients individually

This sounds like TCP to me.  If you want to use just one thread you can use non-blocking NIO. A library which does much of the tricky code for you is netty.

Note: TCP already provides the `getRemoteAddress()` to find out the address of the initiating client.